# Keyboard output reset

Tags: keyboard-layout, 20.10, cinnamon

**Ubuntu 20.10 groovy (x86-64)**

**Kernel: 5.8.0-43-generic**

**Cinnamon: 4.6.7**

**Problem: Keyboard output reset**

My Belgian Keyboard output (layout is ok), resets every time and I have to use the `sudo setxkbmap be` command to set it back every time.
*Exemple: "t^ete" instead of "tête" (means head in French)*

The results I mention are always taken from the terminal itself as reference.
The problem do also appears in some other applications like Messenger(app), Google Docs, ...

Comment: 1. The `setxkbmap` command should be run without `sudo`. 2. Can you please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `cat /etc/default/keyboard` 3. How did you select the layout in the first place? https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: At the first place, it was setup at install of Ubuntu 20.10. The problem apeared after insalling and using Cinnamon. I can't send you those results because I reinstalled my system without Cinnamon this time.

Comment: I see. So you 'solved' the problem, kind of.

Comment: I've reinstalled Cinnamon after all was up to date and restored on my system. This is the result of cat:
`# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.'
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="be"
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS=""
BACKSPACE="guess"`

Comment: Ok. Have you explored [the Cinnamon tool](https://linuxblog.darkduck.com/2016/07/how-to-keyboard-layouts-cinnamon-2.html) for handling keyboard layouts?

Comment: Well, I used the settings in the dock. It appears that afther install of Cinnamon on Ubuntu, after logon, I could see there a "De keyboard" set automaticaly, instead of my initialy set "Be - No dead keys". So I changed it back to "Be - No dead keys". The layout wasn't the trouble but the output gives a problem when using special symbol.
The only symbol that gave me trouble was the one in my example. For the rest, I didn't remark another that has been needed. I've took a look to the link, and need to test more to see what results I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your actual problem is that you chose some other keyboard layout than the one you actually want.

When typing French you need to be able to type accented letters, which means that you should **not** use the *Belgian (no dead keys)* keyboard layout. With that layout, "t^ete" is the expected result if you use the key to the right of the <kbd>P</kbd> key.

When you run `setxkbmap be` you actually switch from *Belgian (no dead keys)* to the basic *Belgian* layout, and then you can successfully type "tête".

So in summary: Open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and change the line

```
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
```

to

```
XKBVARIANT=""
```

Then, after next reboot, it ought to work as expected.

Comment: [French keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY#/media/File:KB_France.svg) vs [Belgian keyboard layout](http://kbdlayout.info/KBDBE/) = They are totaly not the same.
The picture shown as example during the installation of Ubuntu shows all the same buttons on Belgian no dead keys. In Cinnamon Remix install, I had to select French, in order to be able to select Belgian french afterwards. It depens on the setup, what I'll have to choose to find the right one. And on all the systems I tried, the Belgian No dead keys worked fine, even in Ubuntu. Cinnamon on it, output gives trouble.

Comment: I found the right selection thanks to you. In Cinnamon exclusively, I added The Belgian French (without dead keys). This seem to work with the symbol like it should. Even after reboot. In Ibus configuration GUI of Cinnamon, I had to add the keyboard by selecting: French -> Belgian French -> variant (I selected the default one this time)
It's narrow that it reacts so differently depending on the system setup en interpretations. I tought it should apply standards ... But when I see all those types of keyboards I can imagine it's a hell of a job sorting this out.

Comment: In the last release of Ubuntu (22.04) I've tested, during the setup I selected "belgian, belgian" and finaly its output in the system resulted in the taskbar its shown as DE, but it's output seems to be right tough. I can change it, but it would be only to display it right to me as a Belgian. ;)